# How to register dynamic module and send environment variable as an argument

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs, microservices

I'm using NestJS

I have Dynamic module called `RmqModule` and I wanna to consume it in another module

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RmqModule } from '@app/common';


@Module({
    imports: [RmqModule.register({ name: 'this value must come from environment variable and I don\'t know how to get it here' } ), ],
    controllers: [],
    providers: [],
})
export class AnotherModule { }
```

I have to pass a value from environment variable and I don't know hot to do it here

and this is RabbitMQ dynamic Module

```js
import { Module, DynamicModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RmqService } from './rmq.service';
import { ClientsModule, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';


interface RmqModuleOptions {
    name: string;
}

@Module({
    providers: [RmqService],
    exports: [RmqService]
})
export class RmqModule {
    static register({ name }: RmqModuleOptions): DynamicModule {
        return {
            module: RmqModule,
            imports: [
                ClientsModule.registerAsync([
                    {
                        name,
                        useFactory: () => ({
                            transport: Transport.RMQ,
                            options: {
                                urls: [''],
                                queue: '',
                            },
                        }),
                        inject: [],
                    },
                ]),
            ],
            exports: [ClientsModule],
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `process.env.name`. `process.env` is an object that contains the environment variables.

Comment: @rveerd , I would like to use `configModule` , do you know how  ?

Comment: Can you show your `RmqModule`? Did you use Nest's `ConfigurableModuleBuilder` to create it?

Comment: I didn't use ConfigurableModuleBuilder ,

Comment: @rveerd , I added rabbitmq module